# Chrome JS Creating Global KeyEvents

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying out the events and I just realized that my key down event works when it only have focus on the event object. When I click something else the focus is gone and the event doesn't work. So how can I create global key events?

I did search around on google , and came across "Event.addNativePreviewHandler()", there are mostly examples on this which I can't get to work, and the reference page didn't really help me and also I red about a old bug that still occurs now in addNativePreviewHandler and not sure about it.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is the problem. I guess you need to add the event listener on `document` or `window`. The only other global thing is [chrome.commands API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands).

Comment: I did explain though, lets say I have a document with a keydown event. But the event won't fire even if I press unless I click the document but if I click a other element the document's focus is gone and the event wont fire, I have to click the document again to get the event working. So how can I have a key event that doesn't need any focus to fire, and about chrome commands I have to add at least 3 shortcuts, I want only 1 shorcut

Comment: 1) The term "element" usually refers to HTML element which is always a part of "document" in DOM. Did you mean an element of browser UI like the address bar? 2) chrome.commands API doesn't require you to specify 3 shortcuts.

Comment: A element I'm referring to a image in a page, srry I come from a c# background, and I can't load the manifest without adding at least 3 shortcuts in "suggested_key", and in the reference page u showed me, all the examples had 3 shortcuts.

Comment: 1) An image that is a part of the same document shouldn't require special processing so all you need is a document-level listener. However, sometimes the page may cancel an event so you might need to use a capturing phase listener: window.addEventListener('keydown', listenerFn, true), 2) There are different examples https://puu.sh/BUsQ5/4446d262d7.png